# application with Chronicle-Queue memory keeps on growing

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I have implemented a simple Spring Boot application which receive a network message, queue it into SingleChronicleQueue using appender.writeText(str), another thread polls for a message using tailer.readText(). After some processing a processed message is place in another SingleChronicleQueue to be sent away.
I have three queues in the application.

The application rotates the files every night and the first weird thing is that the file sizes (for each Q) are the same (different for every Q).
The largest cq4 file is about 220MB per day.

The problem that I face is that in three days from start until now the memory grew from 480MB to 1.6GB and it just unreasonable.

I have a notion that I am missing something in configuration, or a naive/bad implementation on my part. (I don't close the appender and tailer after every use, should I).

Here is a stripped down example, maybe someone can shed some light.

```
@Service
public class QueuesService {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueuesService.class);

    @Autowired
    AppConfiguration conf;

    private SingleChronicleQueue Q = null;
    private ExcerptAppender QAppender = null;
    private ExcerptTailer QTailer = null;

    public QueuesService() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {

        Q = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(conf.getQueuePath()).indexSpacing(1).build();
        QAppender = Q.acquireAppender();
        QTailer = Q.createTailer();
    }

    public ExcerptAppender getQAppender() {
        return QAppender;
    }

    public ExcerptTailer getQTailer() {
        return QTailer;
    }
}


@Service
public class ProcessingService {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessingService.class);

    @Autowired
    AppConfiguration conf;

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private QueuesService queueService;

    private QueueProcessor processor = null;

    public ProcessingService() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        processor = new QueueProcessor();
        processor.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Message processMessage(Message msg, Map<String, Object> metadata) throws SomeException {

        String strMsg = msg.getMessage().toString();

        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOG.info("\n" + strMsg);
        }

        try {
            queueService.getQAppender().writeText(strMsg);

            if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOG.info("Added new message to queue. index: " + queueService.getQAppender().lastIndexAppended());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unkbown error. reason: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    class QueueProcessor extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while (!interrupted()) {
                try {
                    String msg = queueService.getEpicQTailer().readText();

                    if (msg != null) {
                        long index = queueService.getEpicQTailer().index();
                        // process
                    }
                    else {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOG.warn(e);
                    this.interrupt();
                    break;
                }
            }

            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor tp = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) taskExecutor;
            tp.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chronicle Queue is designed to use virtual memory which can be much larger than main memory (or the heap) without a significant impact on your system.  This allows you to access the data at random quickly.

Here is an example of a process writing 1 TB in 3 hours.

[image]

https://vanilla-java.github.io/2017/01/27/Chronicle-Queue-storing-1-TB-in-virtual-memory-on-a-128-GB-machine.html

This shows how much slower it gets as the queue grows

[image]

Even after it is 1 TB in size on a machine with 128 GB, it write 1 GB under 2 seconds pretty consistently.

While this doesn't cause a technical problem, we are aware this does concern people who also find this "weird", and we plan to have a mode which reduces virtual memory use (even if a little slower for some use cases)

Comment: Hi Pater, thank you so much for answering.Just to clarify, does the queue clears after each cycle?

Comment: @GalNitzan it should after a cycle (i.e. current and last some times). If it doesn't that is a a bug. Some people use hourly cycles instead of daily ones. I prefer daily ones but I can understand people wanting hourly ones.

Comment: Well, actually all I want to see is some memory being freed at midnight after a cycle which I don't, all I see is the memory consumption is growing constantly. I guess I need to debug :(. Thank you for your answers.